# Superscript vs. subscript indices in Euler-Lagrange equation in relativistic field theories

Tags: metric-tensor, relativity, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

In the literature of field theories in flat spacetime, both forms of Euler Lagrange equation are used.

e.g Consider a real scalar field $\phi$

$$\partial_\mu\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi,_\mu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}\qquad\text{where}\qquad\phi,_\mu = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu}\tag{a}$$

$$\partial^\mu\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi,^\mu}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}\qquad\text{where}\qquad\phi,^\mu = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_\mu}\tag{b}$$

Since $\partial^\mu = \pm \partial_{\mu}$, the two forms are obviously equivalent to each other. However, sometimes I am quite uncomfortable with form b. Originally, the spacetime volume element was defined to be $dtdxdydz = \prod_{\mu}dx^\mu$. Form b of the Euler equation implies that we are thinking the Lagrangian and the field $\phi$ as a function of $x_\mu$ in the action integral and in the course of the variational calculation. I would like to know whether it is possible to regard the spacetime volume as $\prod_{\mu}dx_\mu$ so that everything is mathematically consistent?

(I think it is somewhat unnatural to consider the action $ S = \int L $ as an integration with respect to $x_{\mu}$. I do understand that this question may not bear any physical significance but I wish to know the answer for the sake of mathematical clarity.)

Comment: In general, no: the natural setting for integration (and differentiation) is the space of forms. Vectors, on the other hand, require the introduction of extra structure, such as a metric and a connection. Please, leave the volume form as is.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and clarification. I can only partially understand what you mean as my mathematical knowledge is not as sophisticated as yours. On the other hand, my argument goes like this: In a manifold described by a curvilinear coordinate $x^\mu$, there is no such thing as $x_\mu$ as the coordinate $x^\mu$ themselves carry no contravariant vectorial meaning and it will be ridiculous to talk about the covariant counterpart $x_{\mu}$. The coordinate $x^\mu$ is just a label of a point in space and the volume element could only be expressed as $\sqrt{g}\prod_{\mu}dx^\mu$.

Comment: That is entirely correct.

Comment: This comment is a continuation of the last one. For the reasons above, I think it is better to always regard the volume element as $\sqrt{g}\prod_{\mu}dx^\mu$ no matter which kind of geometry and coordinate we are working with.

Answer (score 2):

1. If $x^{\mu}$ with superscript denotes local spacetime coordinates, then we usually$^1$ define the subscript version as $$x_{\mu}  ~:=~ g_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu},$$ where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the (0,2) spacetime metric tensor field.
2. Within [SR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity), we only allow [affine coordinate transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), so that $x^{\mu}$ transforms as (components of) a (1,0) tensor field and $x_{\mu}$ transforms as (components of) a (0,1) tensor field, and you can use both notations.
3. Within [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), we allow general coordinate transformations, and none of $x^{\mu}$ and $x_{\mu}$ then transform as (components of) tensor fields. However $\partial/\partial x^{\mu}$ transforms as (components of) a (0,1) tensor field, while $\partial/\partial x_{\mu}$ doesn't transform as (components of) a (1,0) tensor field. Similarly, $\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}$ transforms as (components of) a (1,0) tensor field, while $\mathrm{d}x_{\mu}$ doesn't transform as (components of) a (0,1) tensor field. Hence the superscript $x^{\mu}$ is preferred in order to maintain covariance.

--

$^1$ This is of course ultimately a question of convention.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Besides considering the transformation properties, we can also understand why it doesn't make sense to consider $x_{\mu}$ in the context of GR. The operation $V_{\mu} = g_{\mu\nu}V^\nu$ only makes sense when $V_{\mu},V^{\nu}$ are really components of some vector V. For a curvilinear coordinate describing a curved spacetime, it is not possible to attribute any vectorial meaning to the coordinate, the coordinate is just a label of point in space. On the other hand, Cartesian coordinate in flat-space(time) are actually components of vector

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I basically agree. (Minor comment: Be careful with the use of the word [curvilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates), which conventionally is restricted to affine spaces.)